# Which directory is opencv "installed" in?

Tags: linux, crunchbang, opencv

Operating System: #! (crunch bang)
Dependencies: opencv

I am attempting to install cvblob (a library for opencv) and I am at the compilation stage in the directions that of which can be seen below.  When I compiled and installed the source code for opencv which directory would be the install directory, the directory in which I unzipped and compiled the source, or some other directory such as /usr/local/lib?  I'm familiar with installing applications in Windows, but I don't seem to see the translation to linux.  For opencv I compiled code and then ran `sudo make install` from within that directory. So for the the line in the directions below

> To indicate where `OpenCV` is, use `OpenCV_DIR` variable:
>
> ```
> `cmake . -DOpenCV_DIR=<path_to_OpenCV>`
> ```

What should I define as the path to opencv?  If further information is needed please let me know.
**DIRECTIONS:**

**Linux**

If you have uncompressed the source in `$CVBLOB`, type in a console:

```
cd $CVBLOB
cmake .
make
```

To indicate where OpenCV is, use OpenCV_DIR variable:

```
cmake . -DOpenCV_DIR=<path_to_OpenCV>
```

**Installation**
Linux

If you have compiled the source in `$CVBLOBBIN`, type in a console:

```
cd $CVBLOBBIN
sudo make install
```

To change the destination path use `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX` when execute `CMAKE`:

```
cmake . -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=<installation_path>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at [github](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/master/CMakeLists.txt) you should have it installed in `/usr/local/` Check what you have got there!

Comment: on ubuntu 14.04 /usr/local/lib

Answer (score 1):

Per answer https://askubuntu.com/a/990597/455406 , if you installed manually you can try

```
pkg-config --libs --cflags opencv
```

Answer (score -2):

To install OpenCV using the terminal on Ubuntu from this article 
http://namhuy.net/1205/how-to-install-opencv-on-ubuntu.html

```
$ su -
# apt-get update
# apt-get install build-essential
# apt-get install libavformat-dev
# apt-get install x264 v4l-utils ffmpeg
# apt-get install libcv2.3 libcvaux2.3 libhighgui2.3 python-opencv opencv-doc libcv-dev libcvaux-dev libhighgui-dev
```

Comment: the OP is asking about the folder OpenCV installed in